# How to navigate through pages? REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Im new to React native.
currently im stuck here.
im trying to create a login application, where home login page will have signup.
on click of signup,should redirect to sign up page.

my app.js is like this.

```
import LoginPage from './src/pages/LoginPage';
import SignupPage from './src/pages/SignupPage';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <RootStack/>
    );
  }
}
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginPage },
  Signup: { screen: SignupPage}  
},
{
  headerMode: 'none',
  navigationOptions: {
    headerVisible: false,
initialRouteName: 'Login'
  }
 }
);
```

my Login page is like this

```
export default class Login extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container}>
            <StatusBar
            backgroundColor="#8c8c8c"
            barStyle="light-content"
            />
            <Logo/>
            <LoginForm />
        </View>
    )
}
}

const {NavigationApp} = createStackNavigator({
signup: {screen: SignupPage}
})
```

my login form is this way:

```
export default class LoginForm extends Component {
    render(){

        return( 
        <View style={styles.container}>
        {/* <Image 
        source={require('../images/Et_cetera_ResizedLogo.png')} /> */}
        {/* <Text style={styles.logoText} >Et ceteraaaa</Text> */}
        <View style={styles.container}>
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.inputBox} 
            placeholder='Email'
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
        />
        <TextInput 
            style={styles.inputBox} 
            placeholder='Password'
            secureTextEntry={true}
            underlineColorAndroid='rgba(0,0,0,0)'
        />
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={styles.buttonStyle}>
                Login
            </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <View style={styles.signup}>
            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.thirdPartyButtonStyle}>
                    Google
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={styles.thirdPartyButtonStyle}>
                    Facebook
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        </View> 
        <View style={styles.signup}>
            <Text style={styles.signupCont}>Don't have an account yet?</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this.props.navigate('signup')}>
            <Text 
                style={styles.signupButton}> Signup
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>

        </View>
    )
}
}
```

so now from here in loginform on click of signup, i want to navigate to signup page.
how can i do that?
any suggestions please.

Answer (score -1):

Use  react-native-router-flux it is quite useful to navigate between scenes

Create a route.js file

```
import {Actions,Router,Stack,Scene} from 'react-native-router-flux';
import Landing from './Register';
import Login from './Login';

export default class Routes extends Component<{}> {

    render(){
        return(
          <Router backAndroidHandler={this.onBackPress}>
            <Stack key="root" hideNavBar={true}>
              <Scene key="landing" component={Login} title="Landing"  initial={true} back/>
              <Scene key="login" component={Register} title="Login"  back/>
            </Stack>
          </Router>
        )
    }

}
```

---

Then add the actions in the login page

```
import {Actions} from 'react-native-router-flux';

signup(){
Actions.signup();
}

export default class Login extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>signup()}>
        <Text>Click Me</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    )
}
}
```

---

```
export default class Register extends Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <View style = {styles.container}>

        <Text>Register Page</Text>

        </View>
    )
}
}
```